# Twitter Reputation System Gem Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I followed the http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system

on my User model i Have:

```
has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source

has_reputation :votes, source: {reputation: :votes, of: :articles}, aggregated_by: :sum

def voted_for?(article)
  evaluations.where(target_type: article.class, target_id: article.id).present?
end
```

Article model i have:

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

And Article controller:

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @article = article.find(params[:id])
  @article.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

But when i go voting shows:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: reputation_name, value,
>   source_id, source_type, target_id, target_type

Anyone is having the same issue with this gem?

Comment: sorry @dimakura, i did not get your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mass assignments error suggest you are using the reputation gem in a Rails 3. You need to downgrade the gem to version 2.

In your Gemfile, specify version 2.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', '~> 2.0', require: 'reputation_system'
```

Then update you bundle.

```
bundle update activerecord-reputation-system
```